# How to create a LinkedHashMultiset<String>?

Tags: java, guava

I'm starting to use the Guava classes and stumbling about the missing constructors.

I have a method that gets a `LinkedHashMultiset<String>`. How do I create a new argument in the method call?

`class.method(LinkedHashMultiset.create());` makes the compiler complain that there is no method for `class.method(LinkedHashMultiset<Object>)`.

And `class.method((LinkedHashMultiset<String)LinkedHashMultiset.create())` fails due to an impossible cast.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is the following:

```
class.method(LinkedHashMultiset.<String>create());
```

One other is this:

```
Multiset<String> multiset = LinkedHashMultiset.create();
class.method(multiset);
```

Answer (score 6):

As with any generic method. EIther the type is deduced by the compiler (type inference):

```
LinkedHashMultiset<String> set = LinkedHashMultiset.create();
```

or it's not, and you have to specify the type:

```
LinkedHashMultiset.<String>create()
```